# Find all the solutions such that $\frac{∂^2g}{∂u∂v} = 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

a) Find all the solutions $g : \mathbb R^2 → \mathbb R$ that have partial derivatives up to the second order that are continuous on $\mathbb R^2$ and such that $\frac{∂^2g}{∂u∂v} = 0$

My attempts:

a) since all partial derivatives of $g$ are continuous, then $\frac{∂^2g}{∂u∂v} = \frac{∂^2g}{∂v∂u}$.

If I set $g(u,v) := h(u)$ and I fix $v$, where $(u,v) \in \mathbb R^2$, then $\frac{∂^2g(u,v)}{∂v∂u} = \frac{∂^2h(u)}{∂v∂u} = \frac{∂}{∂v}(\frac{∂h(u)}{∂u}) = 0$

And since the partial derivatives are continuous, then $\frac{∂}{∂v}(\frac{∂h(u)}{∂u}) = \frac{∂}{∂u}(\frac{∂h(u)}{∂v}) = 0$

But I got stuck here. How to continue from there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial u  \partial v} = 0$
Integrate:
$\frac{\partial g}{\partial u} = f(u)$
Integrate again:
$g(u,v) = h(u)+s(v)$. Where $s$ is any function of $v$ and $h$ is any function of $u$.

Comment: The first integration was w.r.t to $u$, and the second w.r.t $v$?

Comment: @PBC The opposite...First is with respect to variable $v$. And second wrt to $u$. In fact instead of having constants you have functions of the other variable.

Comment: Ah yes! Thank you!

Comment: @PBC You're welcvome...Try to differentiate the first integral...with respect to v you get zero because $f$ is a function of u only .